# Creating a UWP project for Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am trying to add UWP to my Xamarin project, as I have done with `Windows Phone 8.1`. Unfortunately I first saw that `Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs` is not available on `Windows.Phone 8.1`, until I after I had created it and trying to run it, as [this error occurs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/151).

I then tried to add an `UWP project`, but the 1st thing I found wierd, is that it creates 2 projects; `project.UWP.Windows (Windows 8.1)` and `project.UWP.WindowsPhone (Windows Phone 8.1)`. Do it have to create 2 projects or only one?

I followed [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/).

I continued, but then it could not find `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP`. I am using `Xamarin.Forms; version 2.2.0.45` and `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise` on `Windows 10`.

**UPDATE**
I figured out, I have choosen the Universal for `Windows 8.1`, so the problem layed in there.
I created an UWP project now, but it still says `Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.dll'` and `Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.`

I am using these NuGets packages

```
Acr.UserDialogs                              v5.2.2
Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs                     v5.0.0
Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform   v5.1.0
MR.Gestures                                  v1.3.4
SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL               v1.0.0.1
SQLite.Net-PCL                               v3.1.1
Xam.Plugins.Settings                         v2.1.0
Xamarin.Forms                                v2.2.0.45
Xamarin.Insights                             v1.10.6
XLabs.Core                                   v2.2.0-pre2
XLabs.Forms                                  v2.2.0-pre2
XLabs.IoC                                    v2.2.0-pre2
XLabs.Platform                               v2.2.0-pre2
XLabs.Serialization                          v2.2.0-pre2
```

I am using an old version of `Xamarin.Insights` because I was using `Silverlight` before.

Comment: What do you mean by not finding the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP?

Comment: That it can not find the using.

Comment: If there is `Windows 8.1` or `Windows Phone 8.1` in front of it, then it's not a UWP project. I think you created universal projects for Windows 8.1 (yes it's confusing since Windows 10 UWP projects are also called universal...)

Comment: You just need to place it in MainPage XAML:    xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP".

Comment: KooKiz Thanks :D Now it seems better, but it was confusing :(

Comment: @jzeferino I have updated my question to show, what I mean

Comment: What additional nugets are you using? only acr user dialogs?

Comment: @jzeferino I have added a list of all NuGet packages to the question now

Comment: here https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1125 xamarin forms 2.2 and xlabs 2.2 fails to compile. try to use other (lower) version of xlabs. you should open another questions for this. this has been off topic. I recommend remove al dependencies from uwp project a try to compile ir. then add the libraries that you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see in the setup on the right window it shows both Windows 8.1 and Windows  Phone 8.1.

**Window 8.1** is for windows application development. Which can be run on **windows 8.1 PC's**.

**Windows Phone 8.1** is for **Windows phone**, this is windows `mobile application development.`

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/. Its in here, you need to have Windows 10 to create a UWP and the steps are given to add a UWP. Hope this helps.